# Powershell to log into WORKGROUP computers

Tags: powershell

I am creating Powershell script to log into WORKGROUP computers to perform certain actions, but I get a pop-up where I manually have to enter in the password to the computer.

```
$InputFile = 'D:\Script\input.txt'

if(!(Test-Path $InputFile)) {
    Write-Error "File ($InputFile) not found. Script is exiting"
    exit
} 


$Computers = Get-Content -Path $InputFile



$password = Read-Host "Enter the password" -AsSecureString
$confirmpassword = Read-Host "Confirm the password" -AsSecureString
$pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
$pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($confirmpassword))
if($pwd1_text -ne $pwd2_text) {   
    Write-Error "Entered passwords are not same. Script is exiting"
exit
} 

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $Computer    =    $Computer.toupper()
    $Isonline    =    "OFFLINE"
    $Status        =    "SUCCESS"    
    Write-Verbose "Working on $Computer"

    if((Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -count 1 -ErrorAction 0)) {   
        $Isonline = "ONLINE"   
        Write-Output "`t$Computer is Online"
    } 
    else { 
        Write-Output "`t$Computer is OFFLINE" 
    }


    mstsc /v:$Computer


}
```

How do I go through the for loop to automatically log into each computer one-by-one?

Please note, these WORKGROUP computers are dispersed throughout our organization and there is barely any human management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually passwords are accompanied by usernames... not sure what you're planning on doing with just a password.

```
$Credentials = get-credential
Get-Content $InputFile | % { 
    New-PSSession -ComputerName $_ -Credential $Credentials -Name $_
}
```

`Get-Help about_Remoting`
`Get-Help about_PSSessions`